# How to convert cv::MAT byte array sent from C++ to a Bitmap in Java?

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, bitmap

I am receiving a byte array and the width and height of a single channel `cv::Mat` image from C++ through JNI. In Java, I need to create a `Bitmap` out of it for further processing. I have tried the standard options, but I can't decode the `Bitmap` (I keep getting `null`).
The code in JNI is

```
jbyteArray myJByteArray = env->NewByteArray(imageToScan.cols * imageToScan.rows);
env->SetByteArrayRegion(myJByteArray, 0, imageToScan.cols * imageToScan.rows, (jbyte *) imageToScan.data);
```

I am checking the array length as well as the width and height I receive in Java and they're all OK. Now, I have tried the following:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.outHeight = height;
    options.outWidth = width;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
```

but it doesn't work. I know I cannot use `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` as it works only with compressed bitmaps, but don't know how to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Bitmap.createBitmap(int[] colors, int offset, int stride, int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config)` Obviously the first parameter is the uncompressed array.

Comment: What values should I put for stride and config?